# Buffering in flowplayer

Tags: flowplayer

I have a problem with buffering .

This is my code, I set autoBuffering: true but it looks likes not buffering when I am running the video from the server.When Its loading video locally its fine.

```
var player =  $f("player", {        
        src: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf",
        version: [9, 115],
        onFail: function () {
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML =
                     "You need the latest Flash version to see MP4 movies. " +
                        "Your version is " + this.getVersion();
        }
    }, {
        clip: {
            url:"http://path/Videos/04. The White Shirt.mp4
            autoBuffering: true,
            bufferLength : 2, autoPlay: true,
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have no issues when running your code with a mp4 file in my server. I suspect it may have something to do with your server, but if you can provide a link of your server mp4 file then that will make it easier to check. 

Besides, you have set autoplay to be true which will result the autobuffer to be true regardless its setting.

Answer (score 0):

As stating [here](http://chirale.wordpress.com/2009/05/30/video-on-flash-doesnt-buffer-maybe-a-flv-and-mp4-issue/), the issue maybe with the encoding type of the MP4:

> For MP4 files, you have to move MP4 metadata (“moov atom”) from the end of the file to the beginning

Edit: I've just tested qt-faststart (packaged with ffmpeg in Debian): worked like a charm! Just encode your video in MP4, then run:

```
qt-faststart encoded-video.mp4 encoded-for-streaming-video.mp4
```

Size is exactly the same, but video plays immediately.